# How to find the position of objects in java 3d..?

Tags: java-3d

I am using java 3d in my project. I have placed many 3d objects in a 3d environment which are movable using mouse. After moving the objects how can I trace the new position of the moved object? Is there any method in java 3d to do so. Plz help me. Thnx in advance..

Answer (score 3):

```
Transform3D transform = new Transform3D(); 
Vector3f position = new Vector3f();

yourObject.getLocalToVworld(transform); 
transform.get(position);
```

*position* contains your result.